# J-Link GDB debugging in CLion

Tags: debugging, gdb, clion, nrf51, segger-jlink

Not long ago CLion [added support for Remote GDB debugging](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/07/clion-2016-2-eap-remote-gdb-debug/) and I'm trying to set it up with Seggers's J-Link GDB server.

My setup:

- VM VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04
- J-Link drivers: V6.10
- Target chip: nRF51 (ARM Cortex M0)
- CLion 2016.2.2

I usually work in windows, but as CLion doesn't support remote GDB in windows I'm trying to make it work running Ubuntu in VirtualBox. I configured the debugger in CLion like shown in the image with a little help from the blog in the link above. The arguments I have used are based on the J-Link documentation (Document: UM08001) and some guessing.
[GDB server setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESgGS.png)

My problem is that when running the debugger the process just stops and CLion's console outputs:

> "Could not connect to target. Please check power, connection and
>   settings."

I have tried to run JLinkGDBServer from the terminal and then I get as far as this:

```
/usr/bin/JLinkGDBServer -device nrf51422_xxAC -if swd -speed 1000 -endian little
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.10 Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.10 (DLL compiled Sep 14 2016 16:46:16)

-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 nrf51422_xxAC
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link OB-SAM3U128-V2-NordicSemi compiled Jul  5 2016 08:42:09
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 681666518
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...
```

Does anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably confusing GDB server and GDB itself. Those are GDB options that should be set in the GDB Remote Debug Configuration in CLion, not GDB server settings.

That is, you first run JLinkGDBServer manually, for example, from terminal, just as you've done already, and leave it waiting for GDB to attach. At this moment one should notice the connection port:

```
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...
```

Then edit your GDB Remote Debug Configuration in CLion to use the host GDB (most likely `/usr/bin/gdb` in your case, install it using `sudo apt install gdb` if necessary), and use the port mentioned above as part of the "target remote" string:

- GDB: `/usr/bin/gdb`
- "target remote" args: `:2331`

Notice the preceding colon in front of the port. This is a shorthand for connecting to localhost using TCP. Just in case, the explicit form is `tcp:localhost:2331`.

Now you can start the debug session. CLion will start the configured host GDB, GDB communicates to JLinkGDBServer through the specified TCP connection, and finally the GDB server chats with your device.

Comment: Does this can work on IntelliJ community edition? Thanks!

Comment: @Geob-o-matic, nope, this feature is only available in CLion.

Comment: Thank you, stuck with eclipse then… :'(

Comment: @Geob-o-matic You may want to check out a 30-days trial, or start with an EAP version, which is also free.

Comment: I can't do that because the SDK provided is eclipse based and I was just trying to find a "rogue" way to improve my QOL but in the end, I need to stay compatible with eclipse settings anyway to work with my colleagues. And we won't get support from our provider if we use another IDE than the one supplied :)